# Potential energy surface in transition state theory

Tags: quantum-chemistry, ab-initio, reaction-coordinate

I would like to study the typical reaction from the transition state theory:

$$\ce{AB + C <=> ABC^‡ -> A + BC}$$

Assuming $\ce{ABC^‡}$ is a colinear molecule, the potential energy surface of the system is pictured as in [Fig 5.4 on University of Bristol — Potential Energy Surfaces for Triatomic Molecules](http://www.chm.bris.ac.uk/webprojects2002/grant/webcomp/triatomicpes.html):

> [image: Figure 5.4]
>
> **Figure 5.4** - Contour plot PES for a triatomic system. Ligher colours represent greater energies

My questions are:

1. If I project the potential energy from the figure onto the axis $r(\ce{A-B}),$ I would actually plot the potential energy of the triatomic molecule against $r(\ce{A-B}),$ but not the potential energy of the diatomic molecule $\ce{AB}.$ Is that correct?
2. Is there a way to obtain potential curve of molecule $\ce{AB}$ and $\ce{BC}$ as well as the atomic energy level of $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{C}$ from Fig 5.4? (I was given the hint that `WavePacket` program package is able to do this, but I'm not sure how)

Comment: Look for LEPS potentials and you will be able to calculated these for yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Can you provide like an example (paper/website)? Because i tried googling but haven't found what i want

Comment: For the potential this is the original paper:  Sato J Chem Phys v23 p592, there are many other papers, a random selection of which see  Polanyi et al Chem. Phys. v9, p403, 1975, Johnson & Winter, J. Chem. Phys. v66 1977, p4116, Hemphill & White J. Chem. Educ. v49, 1972, p121, Rosenman & Persky, Chem. Phys. v195, 1995, p291.